# how to use exception handling in loop so that loop doesn't break in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, loops, exception, deadlock

I have a postgres function,where I want to handle exceptions in a loop and continue .However this is working fine for normal scenario.on scaling and testing it ends up in a deadlock.I assume this is because of multiple transactions inside the function.is there any way to resolve this without multiple begin-end.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_or_create_abc
    input_dict json)
    RETURNS TABLE(success_list text[], failed_list text[]) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
....

BEGIN
    
    FOR key, value IN SELECT * FROM json_each(input_dict)
    LOOP
    FOR row IN SELECT json_array_elements(value)
    LOOP
    BEGIN
    a := row->>0;
    x := row->>1;
    y := row->>2;
    z := row->>3;
    counter = 0 ;
    WHILE counter < 3 LOOP
    BEGIN
    // functions//
    EXIT;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
       GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS constraint_name_ := CONSTRAINT_NAME;
       IF constraint_name_ = abc THEN
        //..//
       ELSIF constraint_name_ = cde THEN
        //..// 
        exit;
       ELSE
         RAISE;
       END IF;

END;
END LOOP;
END;
end loop;
END LOOP;
    //...//
 RETURN query select success_list,failed_list;
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   //...//
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION protecto_vault.get_or_create_tokens(json)
    OWNER TO test_user;
```

Comment: If you can keep the transactions smaller, do so. It will reduce the likelihood of a deadlock. If it has to be in PL/pgSQL code, you could use a procedure where you can commit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be possible to rewrite this so that you don't need a loop in the first place. Loops can be slow, and I'm guessing if your update/insert ran in a couple statements, it would go quicker, which may prevent the deadlock.

I would recommend batching your data into logical groups that can all be handled together at once, something along the lines of this.

```
    select (exjs ->> 'col1') :: bigint as a,
           (exjs ->> 'col2') :: bigint as x,
           (exjs ->> 'col3') :: int    as y,
           (exjs ->> 'col4') :: date   as z
    from jsonb_array_elements(:your_data) exjs --expanded js
), first_insert as (
insert into some.table(a, x, y, z)
select
    d.a,
    d.x,
    d.y,
    d.z
from data d
where not exists(
    select
        from some.table s
        where s.a = d.a --Ensure that no exceptions will happen when inserting/updating/deleting or whatever you are doing
)
), constraint_handling as (
--     Now handle all the rows that would have hit the exception
    select
        from data d
        where exists (
            select
                from some.table s
                where s.a = d.a
        )
)
select true as finished
;
```

If you are still having issues with hitting constraints during an update like this, you could look at deferring the constraint check until the end of the transaction.

e.g.

```
set constraints your.constraint_name deferred;
--run update
set constraints your.constraint_name immediate;
```

Note that this only works if you created the constraint as deferrable.
e.g.

```
alter table your.table
      add constraint fk_your_key unique (id) deferrable initially immediate;
```

See the [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) manual for more info on deferrable constraints.